# Getting stock prices from internet using web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, finance, stock

Output of my code:

```
<Response [200]>
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NSE-RELIANCE
1
[<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"></div>]

Process Finished with exit code 0
```

I am trying to read stock name from a excel file and update their latest price in my excel sheet using this code. After running this code I am getting the output in a array(data) but that does not contain any stock price, which i could later retrieve and update in my list. Can someone please help me in this?[The html tag highlighted containing the price of stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrwpm.png)

```
import openpyxl
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("try.xlsx")
sheets = wb.sheetnames
#print(sheets)
sh = wb['Stock']
data = sh['F4'].value
#print(data)
s_row = 4
s_col = 6
c_list = []
while sh.cell(row=s_row, column= s_col).value != None:
    c_name = sh.cell(row=s_row, column=s_col).value
    c_list.append(c_name)
    s_row += 1
#print("Company name available in Database")
#[print('    ->', name) for name in c_list]
time.sleep(2)
for stock_symbol in c_list:
    url = 'https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NSE-' + stock_symbol
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
    print(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup)
    data = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last'})
    print(len(data))
    print(data)
```

Comment: looking at the site, it seems that the data is filled in by running scripts. the `requests` module does not run scripts so you cannot get the data you want this way. you will need to use something that WILL run scripts, such as `selenium` or find an alrternate data source

Comment: Just use yfinance library

Answer (score 1):

As I've said in the comments, this data is generated from scripts after page load and `requests` does not run scripts. one way of dealing with this is using something like `selenium` which will also run scripts, another way is to query their API direcly.
After looking at how the data is queried from the site I got this to work:

```
r = requests.post(r"https://scanner.tradingview.com/america/scan", 
    data=json.dumps({"symbols":{"tickers":["NYSE:GME"],"query":{"types":[]}},"columns":["close"]}))
print(r.json())
```

the returned data will look something like this:

```
{'data': [{'s': 'NYSE:GME', 'd': [52.4]}], 'totalCount': 1}
```

notice the value in `"tickers"` and the `"columns"`
here is a more expansive list of columns if you need more data

```
['Recommend.All', 'RSI', 'RSI[1]', 'Stoch.K', 'Stoch.D', 'Stoch.K[1]', 'Stoch.D[1]', 'CCI20', 'CCI20[1]', 'ADX', 'ADX+DI', 'ADX-DI', 'ADX+DI[1]', 'ADX-DI[1]', 'AO', 'AO[1]', 'Mom', 'Mom[1]', 'MACD.macd', 'MACD.signal', 'Rec.Stoch.RSI', 'Stoch.RSI.K', 'Rec.WR', 'W.R', 'Rec.BBPower', 'BBPower', 'Rec.UO', 'UO', 'EMA10', 'close', 'SMA10', 'EMA20', 'SMA20', 'EMA30', 'SMA30', 'EMA50', 'SMA50', 'EMA100', 'SMA100', 'EMA200', 'SMA200', 'Rec.Ichimoku', 'Ichimoku.BLine', 'Rec.VWMA', 'VWMA', 'Rec.HullMA9', 'HullMA9']
```